# Issues with translating the strings

Tags: django, multilingual, django-multilingual

I am using **multiple translation** in my project

For that I have updated my **settings file** as

```
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    gettext = lambda s: s


    LANGUAGES = (

        ('es', gettext('Spanish')),
        ('en', gettext('English')),
    )


    LOCALE_PATHS = (
        '/mnt/aviesta/pythondev/django/locale',
    )

    USE_I18N = True
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',


TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

And my **template file** as:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% trans "Hello" %}


<p>Already a user <a href="/login/"><b>{% trans "login here" %}</b></a></p>
```

after that I create a locale folder parallel to my app and than create the specific language folders in it as :**django-admin.py makemessages -l es** which creates the .po file and then update this .po file as:

```
#: customer_reg/customer_register.html:14
msgid "Hello"
msgstr "¡Hola"

#: customer_reg/customer_register.html:17
msgid "login here"
msgstr "ingresa aquí"
```

And finally i *compiled* my msg **django-admin.py compilemessages**

BUt my strings "hello" and "login here" is remain in **English**, they are not translated.I don't know why it happens ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks great with your code. The only thing I've never seen is the `LOCALE_PATHS` in `settings.py`

Mabye this answer, I did some time ago, could help you: [Issues with multiple languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852805/issues-with-multiple-languages/12853503#12853503)

**Edit // Answer to comment**

```
from django.utils import translation
translation.activate('es')
```

Comment: If I do not select any language and open my url as usual **www.asd.com/reg ** it will select the spanish language or default language ??

Comment: depends on your locale settings of your browser. If django can't get any locale it will display the default (in your case english) language.

Comment: I mean to say if I wants that spanish lang. work properly is there anything I have to write in my view or anywhere else that I mention in my question.

Comment: If you want to force django to use spanish for that view, yes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18087/discussion-between-init3-and-user1746291)