# issues with url in multiple languages

Tags: django, multilingual, django-urls, django-multilingual

I am using  the concept of multiple languages in my project, and everything works fine.

But i am having some queries about my url.

When i am using this *url* **www.asd.com/reg/?lang=es**, then it display the data in spanish form.

But if i am using this *url* **www.asd.com/reg/lang=es**, then it does not display data in spanish.

The difference between two url is **"?"** , so can anybody suggest me some way with which I can accomplish my task without this **"?"**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to post variables without the `?` in your URL. ([more informations here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get))

If you want to manage it without the GET-Parameter (`?lang`) you need to rewrite the [middleware I've posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907870/issues-with-translating-the-strings/12908001#12908001) to you. Also you need to modify your `urls.py`.

All you then may achieve is `www.asd.com/reg/lang/es` or `http://es.asd.com/reg` if you're familiar with subdomaining.

Comment: I tried to modify this middleware but I am unable to solve my problem so please can u tell me how can i do that?? **thanks**