# How to retrieve language settings from within view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-multilingual

I want to set up a very small site in three different languages.

Basically I want to use a **single  view** that sends back different data **to the same template** dependent on the selected language (all data is in one table anyway).

I just read through the [internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code) documentation which gives a good overview but I still don't really get how to render the right kind of content based on a selected language. It seems as if I can extract this information with the [requestcontext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) class but how exactly? Or am I over complicating things? Can somebody provide a good example?

Comment: Have you already gone through [how django detects language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)?

Comment: Thanks for the link Burhan, I must have missed this part. Just to make sure: if I use [redirect-view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) to set the user preference I'll be set with `request` functions within my view?

Comment: Plus you should make sure you use request context (ie, use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me/render) or CBV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
from django.utils import translation
language= translation.get_language_from_request(request)
translation.activate(language)
```

And maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852805/issues-with-multiple-languages/12853503#12853503) could help you, too.

Comment: Thanks mate. I can't test right now but will come back to it later.